# POST Http request with JSON object

Tags: java, http-headers, http-post, jsoup

I'm working on a pet project to scrape fantasy football stats from MY own fantasy league on ESPN. The problem that I'm running into that I can't seem to get past is the login which is needed before I can make requests for my league's page.

The URL I hit is

> http://games.espn.com/ffl/leaguesetup/ownerinfo?leagueId=123456&seasonId=2016

and by looking at the GET requests it looks like I get redirected to

> http://games.espn.com/ffl/signin?redir=http://games.espn.com/ffl/leaguesetup/ownerinfo?leagueId=123456&seasonId=2016

Which immediately gets me to a login prompt window. When I log in I inspect the POST request and note down all the Request Header. Looks like the requested URL on the POST is

> https://registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v5/client/ESPN-FANTASYLM-PROD/guest/login?langPref=en-US

additionally I noted the following JSON objected is passed along:

```
        {"loginValue":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}
```

using the Request Headers and JSON object I did the following:

```
        String url = "http://games.espn.com/ffl/leaguesetup/ownerinfo?leagueId=123456&seasonId=2016";
        String rawData = "{\"loginValue\":\"myusername\",\"password\":\"mypassword\"}";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "APIKEY 8IYGqTgmpFTX51iF1ldp6MBtWrdQ0BxNUf8bg5/empOdV4u16KUSrnkJqy1DXy+QxV8RaxKq45o2sM8Omos/DlHYhQ==");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "52");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Expires", "-1");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "registerdisney.go.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("Origin", "https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com/v2/ESPN-ESPNCOM-PROD/en-US?include=config,l10n,js,html&scheme=http&postMessageOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2F&cookieDomain=www.espn.com&config=PROD&logLevel=INFO&topHost=www.espn.com&ageBand=ADULT&countryCode=US&cssOverride=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.espncdn.com%2Fcombiner%2Fc%3Fcss%3Ddisneyid%2Fcore.css&responderPage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Flogin%2Fresponder%2Findex.html&buildId=157599bfa88");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("conversation-id", "5a4572f4-c940-454c-8f86-9af27345c894, adffddd3-8c31-41a0-84d7-7a0401cd2ad0");
        con.setRequestProperty("correlation-id", "4d9ddc78-b00e-4c5a-8eec-87622961fd34")

        con.setDoOutput(true);`           
        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        w.write(rawData);
        w.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

Assuming I'm on the right track what I'm currently getting back from the server is server is

> returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v5/client/ESPN-FANTASYLM-PROD/guest/login?langPref=en-US

Any ideas what is happening or if i'm taking the complete wrong approach here? I tried to use JSoup but had no luck either and I believe underneath JSoup uses HttpUrlConnection as well.

Do I need to do some sort of GET request first, save something then do the POST request? How should it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to emulate the behaviour of a Web Browser with JSoup. As you have experienced this is quite complicated and JSoup is not made for to impersonate a browser. When you start with crafting HTTP headers, then it's better to go another way.

The solution for your problem is to use a browser that can be programmatically manipulated. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is more or less the defacto standard in Java.

Selenium starts your favorite browser (Firefox, Chrome, ..) and let you control it from your Java program. You can also retrieve the content of the web pages in order to scrap them with JSoup. Selenium is well documented, you will have no difficulty to find the required documentation/tutorial.

Comment: I've worked with Selenium before for automating UI tests and it works great but that's not really what I'm after here. What I want/need is to be able to retrieve the HTML without having to launch a browser.

Comment: It is nowaday nearly impossible to retrieve HTML from complex websites, especially those with user interactions, without having to launch a browser. If you want to emulate one interaction you may programatically go through (managing cookies is no fun) but this approach does not scale.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to your problem. While it is impossible for me to reproduce your issue (don't have football fantasy account and I have no intent to create one), I can still try to give some methodology help.

I would tackle the problem by using the network inspector from my browser, copy in a file all the exchanges between the browser and the server and try to reproduce this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The API key value in the Authorization header can only be reused for a limited time. If it is expired, the registration response body will contain an "API_KEY_INVALID" error.